# How do I correctly use 3D Perlin Noise as turbulence for my particle system?

Tags: c++, particle-system, perlin-noise

So I am working on a particle system, mainly as a learning exercise on the CPU, using Visual Studio C++. It's looking pretty neat!

The latest thing I'm attempting is to add turbulence using 3D perlin noise. I found this fellow's code: https://blog.kazade.co.uk/2014/05/a-public-domain-c11-1d2d3d-perlin-noise.html

I implemented it correctly. I know this, because I can draw solid, working Perlin noise within my app, and it draws it correctly, also taking into account octaves, amplitude and frequency, which I added access to. So far, so good.

The problem is that I don't know how to use this correctly for displacing particle motion. This is currently my implementation (px0, py0, pz0 are my particle positions in -1.0 to 1.0 screen-space range. 0.1 is just to scale values down to a usable amount):

```
//Initialize octaves, seed, amplitude, frequency
noise::PerlinOctave perlin(octaves, seed, amplitude, frequency);

// Call the noise function
float n = perlin.noise(px0,py0,pz0) * 0.1;
px0 += n;
py0 += n;
pz0 += n;
```

This produces ok results but when I adjust the amplitude, my particles move **diagonally**. This is usually due to using addition which makes me think perhaps I shouldn't be adding noise to the particle positions but rather multiplying. However, I haven't had any success trying that.

I also tried unsuccessfully assigning 1D Perlin noise to every axis like this:

```
px0 += perlin.noise(px0) * 0.1;
py0 += perlin.noise(py0) * 0.1;
pz0 += perlin.noise(pz0) * 0.1;
```

The noise function returns a value of -1.0 to 1.0 (I believe) and my particle screen-space also works that same range so there should be no need to remap the noise to 0.0-1.0.

So I can't think of anything else to try. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thank you all in advance!
-Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a few things backwards here.

3D Perlin noise defines a noise function that takes a 3D input, to provide you with a 1D output. What you need is something that takes a 3D input, and gives you a 3D output.

You could achieve this by having 3x3D noises....

```cpp
noise::PerlinOctave3D perlinX(octaves, seedX, amplitudeX, frequencyX);
noise::PerlinOctave3D perlinY(octaves, seedY, amplitudeY, frequencyY);
noise::PerlinOctave3D perlinZ(octaves, seedZ, amplitudeZ, frequencyZ);

// Call the noise function(s)
float nx = perlinX.noise(px0,py0,pz0) * 0.1;
float ny = perlinY.noise(px0,py0,pz0) * 0.1;
float nz = perlinZ.noise(px0,py0,pz0) * 0.1;
px0 += nx;
py0 += ny;
pz0 += nz;
```

Using 3x1D noise funcs would also work (maybe not that well, but it will work)

```cpp
noise::PerlinOctave1D perlinX(octaves, seedX, amplitudeX, frequencyX);
noise::PerlinOctave1D perlinY(octaves, seedY, amplitudeY, frequencyY);
noise::PerlinOctave1D perlinZ(octaves, seedZ, amplitudeZ, frequencyZ);

// Call the noise function(s)
float nx = perlinX.noise(px0) * 0.1;
float ny = perlinY.noise(py0) * 0.1;
float nz = perlinZ.noise(pz0) * 0.1;
px0 += nx;
py0 += ny;
pz0 += nz;
```

Even using 2D funcs would work (and be a bit cheaper than 3x3D funcs).

```cpp
noise::PerlinOctave2D perlinX(octaves, seedX, amplitudeX, frequencyX);
noise::PerlinOctave2D perlinY(octaves, seedY, amplitudeY, frequencyY);
noise::PerlinOctave2D perlinZ(octaves, seedZ, amplitudeZ, frequencyZ);

// Call the noise function(s)
float nx = perlinX.noise(px0, py0) * 0.1;
float ny = perlinY.noise(py0, pz0) * 0.1;
float nz = perlinZ.noise(pz0, px0) * 0.1;
px0 += nx;
py0 += ny;
pz0 += nz;
```

If you are modelling turbulence though, you probably want to be extracting the noise to be used as a force to apply to the particles, rather than simply using the result to directly modify the position.

Comment: Hi @robthebloke - Thank you for your detailed reply. Wow, seems more complicated than I thought. I had taken a look at this thread and tried that: https://gamedev.net/forums/topic/461153-using-perlin-noise-to-generate-wind-turbulence-for-particle-effects/4041571/ And also this one: https://davenewt.github.io/p5-perlin-noise/ Perhaps what I'll try is expanding the Perlin Noise function to 3 of them as you have suggested, and see the results of that. I will come back and post what I find. I just didn't see other examples requiring multiple calls. Are you sure that is how it must be done?

Comment: The 3D part is how you want to index the noise. The source code example at that site is storing a double per lattice point. You could attempt to expand that so that it stores a vec3 per point instead. By and large there are no strict rules for how it _should_ be done, you typically end up using the cheapest method that looks good enough for your needs.

Comment: In the above case you are writing a 3D particle system, with a need for a 3D vector as an output. So in this case you will need to reformulate what you have to give you those constraints. In my mind, having a turbulence field where the output is the same magnitude in all directions isn't all that turbulent.

Comment: Hi @robtheblok - thank you so much again for your advice. I reworked my code to what you suggested and the turbulence effect looks awesome now! It is working really well. Thanks for all your help and I'll mark your answer correct now. :)